# What response are web crawlers expecting at `/api/.env`?

Tags: web-crawler, single-page-application, api-design

Recent activity in the server web logs show a periodic burst of requests for `/api/.env` to which the server responds with `404 NOT FOUND`.

The requests appear to be coming from Microsoft Azure owned IP addresses, and my suspicion is they're originating from web-crawlers, possibly from Bing.

This is a Single Page Application (SPA), and the API endpoints the SPA uses are on the same URL at `/api` but I haven't been able to find any documentation about what a request for `/api/.env` or `.env` should contain.

**What should a request for `/api/.env` return?**

Comment: Sometimes configurations or environment variables are stored in `.env` file, such as `DBA_PASSWORD` or `DBA_ADDRESS`. Look at this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv. To me it sounds like an attempt to find sensible infos.